# making a schedueled task run mnimized

Tags: windows-7, batch, windows-task-scheduler

I have a batch file that I run once an hour via Windows Scheduler. Unfortunately, it can take several tens of minutes for this batch file to finish running.

Is there a way to make the batch file start out minimized?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't care about seeing the batch at all, just schedule it to run under a different user account. you can create a user for that purpose, or run it under one of the existing service user accounts (NETWORK SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE, etc). the terminal won't appear on your desktop.

if you do want to be able to watch it, but just want to start minimized, check out 'start /min'

```
cmd.exe /c start /min example.bat ^& exit
```

Comment: Can also hide the cmd window using VBS.